# Smooth text scrolling in C#

Tags: c#, text, scroll

i would like to have text that scrolls **smoothly** on my c# windows form.

i tried to define that label with text on it moves pixel by pixel, but it is not smooth as it is like animations created in flash.

how can i manage to get such smooth animation?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide more info so I can give you more detailed answer.  For example, what is the speed of your scrolling text?

Comment: If i may (do not downvote), an easier way is to have a scrollable control, and all you to do, is a timer that gradually moves the "hidden" scrollbar, creating scrollable credits that are pretty smooth,... :)

Answer (score 6):

I have tried to do it and I've got some good news and some bad news.

The good news is that it is possible. I am testing the code right now and I can achieve absolutely silky smooth text scrolling even with GDI+.

The tough part is that there are quite a few things you must ensure / implement to have it:

1. Set DoubleBuffered to true on your rendering surface (e.g. your form).
2. You have to draw the text yourself,
   the Label class will not do (see
   next point as to why).
3. You need floating point resolution
   in your drawing (positioning) code,
   which means you must use
   TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias in your
   DrawString() calls and bigger font sizes (>10-12 pt) to make it look good.
4. You need a very high resolution
   timer component. I am using a
   component based on Win32 multimedia
   timers in winmm.dll that allows for
   timer event rates up to 1000 Hz and
   almost absolute accuracy (standard
   deviation below 0.1 ms). Google for
   MultimediaTimer component. (BTW, I know it is no longer the solution recommended by MS, but it works perfectly even in Windows 7.)
5. Also, the Windows multimedia timer
   has a millisecond resolution, which
   cannot give you perfect 60 Hz
   refresh (1000/60 is not an integer),
   so you will need to implement some
   kind of a floating point display
   refresh counting mechanism to get as
   close to the display refresh rate as
   possible. Something along the lines
   of

   ```
   float tickCount = 0.0f;
   float tickDelta = 1000.0f / 60.0f;


   void mmTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       tickCount++;
       if (tickCount >= tickDelta)
       {
           tickCount -= tickDelta;
           // scroll your text here 
           Invalidate();
       }
   }
   ```

   will do.
6. Finally, some minor tearing might
   happen occasionally. This is all
   but inevitable, as you have no
   access to vertical sync video
   registers. Experiment with timings
   to eliminate tearing.

I honestly hope this helps. Let me know if you have any problems implementing it.

Comment: for me it's ok if i work not with labels, but with images. i guess that i can implement your solution on sliding image?

Comment: @user198003: Sure, it will work with any graphic object. I used DrawString() in the rendering code, but any System.Drawing.Graphics method will work. Don't make the image too large, though, or you'll see more tearing regardless of the scrolling speed (remember, there is no VSync without DirectX).

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you use double buffering, because without it, your text WILL blink and won't look very nice at all.

There is the issue with GDI that you probably have, and that's you moving speed isn't synced with monitor refresh rate.

If you have 60Hz LCD monitor for example, you should update text position every 1000/60 ms, but if you use timer for that, you'll experience jerkiness now and then.

Comment: This would cause it to flash, instead of not being smooth enough, and could be solved by turning double buffering on.

Comment: I assumed that double buffering is used - without it it would really look very very bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the read-only property CreateParams on your form and add WX_COMPOSITE ( 0x2000000, I think that is composite ) to the params. This only works on XP and up, but it stops flickering where DoubleBuffer doesn't.